# OBJ Model not loading in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to add an OBJ Model (armchair.obj) but it's not being loaded. I'm using React three fiber library.

Here's my codesandbox: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hill-fxyl4y?file=/src/App.js)

There's no problem with the model because I tried to load it using some other [website](https://3dviewer.net/) and it is being loaded.

Anyway, I tried uploading another model (spongebob.obj) but it's not being really visible

[image: Spongebob obj]

However, in the other website, it's visible:

[image: third party website]

So, here's my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hill-fxyl4y?file=/src/App.js)

But, if you prefer the code here:

My App.js component:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import LoadModel from "./components/LoadModel";
import Loader from "./components/Loader";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <main className="main-area">
            <div id="canvas-container">
            <Canvas pixelratio={[1, 2]} camera={{ position: [15, 15, 15], fov: 50, scale: [2,2,2] }}>
                <ambientLight intensity={1} />
                <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                    <LoadModel url="./spongebob.obj" />
                </Suspense>
                <OrbitControls />
            </Canvas>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
};

export default App;
```

My LoadModel.js component:

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";

const LoadModel = ({ url }) => {
  const [obj, set] = useState();

  // useMemo(() => new OBJLoader().load(url, set), [url])
  useMemo(() => new OBJLoader().load(url, set), [url]);
  //useMemo(() => new GLTFLoader().load(url, set), [url])

  return obj ? <primitive object={obj} dispose={null} /> : null;
};

export default LoadModel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the rendering of the SpongeBob model by adding a directional light to your scene. A single ambient light is not sufficient for proper illumination. Try adding the following line to your codesandbox:

```
<directionalLight />
```

The chair model has unfortunately some design issues. It has an extreme scale and is highly translated. I suggest you scale the model down and then center it after the loading process. However, it would be better to fix the model in a DCC tool like Blender and model the chair according to real world units.